# Woocommerce product import not honoring 'wc_product_has_unique_sku' filter

Tags: php, wordpress, csv, woocommerce

I'm trying to import a csv of products into a WooCommerce store. The products can have duplicate SKU fields with the following filter.

```
add_filter( 'wc_product_has_unique_sku', '__return_false' );
```

The importer doesn't seem to honor this though and refused to import any duplicates.

Does anyone know how to make this work?

Comment: Where are you adding this code?

Comment: Are you getting a PHP error due to argument count? `wc_product_has_unique_sku` is a filter with 3 parameters.

Comment: I'm adding this in functions.php of my theme.

Comment: Could you solve ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure this code is in your active theme, if it is already in active theme then I believe there is some confliction with theme or plugin.